# Normalising/Standardising Data for Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification, normalization, standardization

If we have a system in which we normalise and standardise the data, I'm interested into how to most effectively do this.

For a test system we can apply normalisation and standardisation techniques to all data samples. E.g.: via a method that uses the maximum and minimum to normalise in-between 0 and 1. However, in practice we won't know the maximum and minimum for a feature because a new unseen sample may be obtained that has a greater value than the previous maximum value we used to normalise.

Is there a solution to this problem that I see?

Answer (score 2):

Z score scaling involves subtracting each column's mean from it, and then dividing by the SD.

**Important** when you do this: save those means and SDs from your training set, and use them to transform your test and prediction sets. Don't use the statistics from the test set.

To see why, think about what would happen if your training dataset was all human heights from Japan, while your test set was human heights from Kenya.  You'd be making them appear identical, when they are not.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts without going into articles or maths.

If you choose to normalize the data based on the sample data that you have available by dividing by say the max, min values of the data as suggested it is clear that you would need to apply the same normalization on new data.

To me it is not clear exactly what is the problem, though, could be more specific in which circumstances this has practical relevance? Speaking hypotetically about it you could come up with a larger normalization constant, not found in the data etc and say this is valid under these circumstances. Say take max and multiply with 100 or something.

To make it a bit more meaningful and interesting though I would need more details. Otherwise you risk ending up with a hypotethial question like, without any assumptions on the new data that my machine learning will handle, how can I know that it fits into the data range where my model has somekind of relevance, and the obvious answer to such rather philosophical questions is that you cannot. Don't know if that is helpful. I would be happy to have someone more experienced to give their input as well.

Comment: This gives some useful starting points, thank you!

Comment: It is a bad idea to apply a different function to the training and test data. If they ha e a different distribution' you're just throwing that info away

Answer (score 0):

Yes.If your cause of worry is that 'a new unseen sample may be obtained that has a greater value than the previous maximum value we used to normalize'.You can always use Standardisation.

---

For example : 
suppose data are 1, 2, 3 so mean is 2 and SD 1. So, standardized values are now -1, 0, 1. Let Next value that is added is 4.
After adding the new data point 4 in the data set (1,2,3): The mean becomes 2.5 and SD become 1.2909944487358. So, the new standardized value becomes - 1.16189500386, - 0.38729833462, 0.38729833462, 1.16189500386. Also, the new standardized value mean is zero and SD is 1.

---

If you perform column standardization on your data set, You would not have to worry about the minimum and maximum value. The column standardization method of data pre-processing will automatically align all your data points with a mean of Zero and Standard deviation of 1.

Comment: This makes no sense. As new data arrive, then the previous minimum and maximum indeed may no longer hold: records can be broken. But equally as new data arrive, the previous mean and SD may no longer be right either.. In particular, a new maximum or a new minimum **must** shift the mean and SD. So, there is no advantage for (value $-$ mean) / SD over (value $-$ minimum) / (maximum $-$ minimum) in this respect.

Comment: Agree. But It definitely makes sense when you apply standardization on the new data points too before applying Dimensionality reduction algorithms like PCA and t-SNE. Doesn't it? 
So, in that case, you need not worry about Min and Max values.

Comment: Your reaction to my comment is puzzling. "Agree" perhaps implies that you should delete your answer as wrong. For PCA, correlations between variables are invariant under any linear rescaling.

Comment: Agree with the statement, " As new data arrive, then the previous minimum and maximum indeed may no longer hold: records can be broken. But equally.......... no advantage for (value − mean) / SD over (value − minimum) / (maximum − minimum) in this respect" but in case if someone is worried about min and max value being changed after adding new data points then Column standardization is definitely the choice keeping in mind the fact that, every newly added data point must be standardized so that the mean and standard deviation do not change).

Comment: Not so: the mean and SD need updating with new data. What you suggest, if I understand you, just falsifies data. Suppose data are 1, 2, 3 so mean is 2 and SD 1. So, standardized values are now -1, 0, 1. Next value is 4; how do you deal with that?

Comment: After adding the new data point 4 in the data set (1,2,3) : The mean becomes 2.5 and SD become 1.2909944487358. So, the new standardized value becomes - 1.16189500386, - 0.38729833462, 0.38729833462, 1.16189500386. Also, the new standardized value mean is zero and  SD is 1.

Comment: Quite, but the previous standardized values need to be changed too. So, as said, both scalings need updating and the argument in your answer collapses.

Comment: My answer was according to the question asked. Simply said: If someone's worry is about max and min value being changed after adding new data points. I would not use any data pre-processing techniques that require min and max values. I would simply prefer Standardization which only need mean and SD.
Also, i am editing the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Sorry to be stubborn, but your new answer is as muddy as the first version. Updating is needed in both cases; there is no merit in pointing out that if you're worried about updating with one method, then you can update with another method. You need to and can update in either case, and it is  easy code in any software. But I'll back out now.